# Digit 2 Appended to Field Name on Column in Entity Field Query

Tags: entities

I have an Entity Field Query that has *fieldCondition* for *field_email*

```
  ->fieldCondition('field_email', 'value', $email , '=');
```

I have verified that this is the name of the field and I have other entity queries that use this field correctly.  However, in this example, Drupal is adding the digit *2* on to the field name as I understand the error returned.

```
$dup_query1 = new EntityFieldQuery(); 
$dup_query1->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node') ->entityCondition('bundle', 'fair_participant')
 ->fieldCondition('field_last_name', 'value', $last_name , '=')
 ->fieldCondition('field_first_name', 'value', $first_name , '=')
 ->fieldCondition('field_email', 'value', $email , '='); 

$fpmatch_fandl_email = $dup_query1->execute();
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'field_data_field_email2.field_email_value' in 'where clause'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I believe that is an alias in the query

Comment: What is the full code of the Entity Field Query?

Comment: Here is the query.  Thank you. ` $dup_query1 = new EntityFieldQuery();
            $dup_query1->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                ->entityCondition('bundle', 'fair_participant')
                ->fieldCondition('field_last_name', 'value', $last_name , '=')
                ->fieldCondition('field_first_name', 'value', $first_name , '=')
                ->fieldCondition('field_email', 'value', $email , '=');

            $fpmatch_fandl_email = $dup_query1->execute();`

Comment: do you use [email](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module, use `email` instead of `value`, because the module store the value in `field_name_email` not `field_name_value` like other field like text ... 
So you Query should be like:

```
$dup_query1 = new EntityFieldQuery();
$dup_query1->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node') 
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'fair_participant')
    ->fieldCondition('field_last_name', 'value', $last_name , '=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_first_name', 'value', $first_name , '=')
    // use email not value.
    ->fieldCondition('field_email', 'email', $email , '=');

$fpmatch_fandl_email = $dup_query1->execute();
```